# How can I create an ActiveAdmin filter that will show only objects without a value specified?

Tags: activeadmin, ransack

I am using the latest ActiveAdmin and I am trying to create a filter for a model that has a belongs_to relationship with another model, and therefor has a column litigation_canonical_docket_event_id that refers to that model.

How can I create a filter that will show only objects that do (or do not) have a value in that ID column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use activeadmin's `collection` attribute with proc to customize your query. For example:

```
filter :your_model_field, :collection => proc { YourModel.where("litigation_canonical_docket_event_id IS NOT NULL") }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a standard model scope, then making that scope ransacakable, then referring to it as a filter. The above comment might work if I wanted to find all items that have a specific value but what I am after is finding whether it has any value (or not).